# “$f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$” vs. “$f $is a function from $A$ into $B$”?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, terminology

When we say that

> $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$

is this different from saying

> $f$ is a function from $A$ into $B$

I know what injective ("1-1"), surjective ("onto"), and bijective functions are, but is there such a thing as an "into" function?

Comment: some people prefer "onto" instead of "surjective", and then "into" makes sense as the analogue of "injective", but i think most people would just interpret it as the same as "$f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$"

Comment: I think this is a perfectly fair question, unsure why it was downvoted.

Comment: As a non-english motherboard I'd kill anyone that uses this kind of terminology, since *into*, *onto*, *to* seem more or less the same and are easily confused. I'd personally say "$f$ is an injection/surjection from $A$ to $B$" if I want to add that information without adding adjectives.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***Both expressions say the same thing***.

But note that saying "$f: A \to B$ is a function from $A$ into $B$ does **not** imply that $f$ is *into* but *not onto* (i.e., it does **not** rule out that $f$ might be onto, so it is not the "converse" of, or the negation of, the descriptor "onto" or "surjective"). Indeed, it says nothing more, and nothing less, than the alternative: "$f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$."

- So we can either say that there is no such thing as an "into function" (i.e. it is NOT used to describe some, but not all functions, nor is it describe *particular kinds of functions*),
- Or we can say that *every function is into* (meaning every function $f: A \to B$ is a function on $A$ into $B$.)

Comment: Nice write up! +1

Comment: Thank you for the edit, @ruakh!

Comment: As Celine songs: Fly, Fly little one....:-)

Comment: @amWhy , thanx , one strange thing is that i have 17+ upvotes ! when i asked the question , i hoped that it will not be closed because it doesn't satisfies the politics of the site as it has no useful information for others in future  !

Comment: Never second guess yourself, @Maths Lover ! You're making excellent progress, and have you noticed that your posts have improved dramatically with respect to your earliest of posts? I've witnessed a lot of growth: both in your maturity, and intellectually!

Comment: @amWhy , thanx for you kind words :) i hope i keep improving , in reality , this progress is by dint of the members here such that you , Babak , Azmoti , Jack Schmidt, DonAntonio ,Alexander Gruber and many many other great members in the site . Great thank you all .

Comment: @amWhy , in reality , main reason of this is by dint of you , you have answered many many of may questions in excellent way .

Comment: Thanks, MathsLover! I love math as much as you ;-)

Answer (score 11):

Both mean the same thing.   There is no such thing as an "into" function.

Answer (score 8):

*Any* function $f : A \to B$ is said to map $A$ *into* $B$ or to be a mapping from $A$ into $B$. The term *into* is used in general for any function, it doesn't relate to any specific kind of functions.

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference between "to" and "into" here.

In [Gelbaum and Olmstead's *Counterexamples in Analysis*](http://books.google.com/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC), they use this terminology in a way that makes it seem slightly more reasonable (though I personally still wouldn't ever use "into").

> [image]